# C identifying the library name for -l flag?

Tags: c, gcc

When including a library for gcc (-l or lower case -L) how would I know the library name to put inside that parameter for a specific header file?

an example (but I am looking for a more general answer):

my c file (named doSomething.c) might have:

```
#include <libv4l2.h>
...
...
```

my gcc statement would look like:

```
gcc -o doSomething doSomething.c -lv4l2
```

In this case I knew I needed to include the library v4l2, if I hadn't known is there a generic way of finding that name?

any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: There is no systematic way to know, but the documentation for the library you're trying to use should explain.

Comment: Basically, you don't understand how library works ? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Rephrased the question ignore the last part essentially how do I find the name of what goes inside the -l field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever supplied you with the library should tell you its name. Often, that is vague, implied, buried in documentation, or left to convention.

To start with, you can pass any library to the linker by using the full path in the file system, such as /usr/lib/libfoo.so or ~myaccount/mystuff/bar.a.

The linker has a built-in list of standard places to look for libraries, so you can leave off the directory part of the path and just name the file, like libfoo.so. You can also add directories to this list with the -L switch (for common linkers on POSIX and other systems).

If the file name has the form lib*foo*.a or other extensions recognized by the linker, you can abbreviate it with -l*foo*.

So, if the library is installed in a standard place with a standard name, you can link it with -l*foo*, and the vendor or other supplier should tell you what *foo* is.

If the library is part of a software package that is installed on your system but is not a standard part of the system, you can ask your system administrator what the name is, and, if it is not in a standard location, where they installed it.

Comment: No slash after the tilde?

Comment: @iBug: “~” means my home folder. “~xyz” means the home folder of the account named xyz.

Comment: just for further elaboration on the topic would /usr/lib or would this be something very OS specific?

Comment: @test123: /usr/lib is just an example. It is OS specific (but I would not say very OS specific; Unix and Unix-like systems are quite common). Microsoft Windows uses different paths, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The name of a linker-library in a POSIX environment (like Linux) have a special format.

A static library (basically an archive of object files) have the format `libname.a`.

A dynamic library have the format `libname.so`. Possibly with some version number appended at the end (like e.g. `libname.so.1` or `libname.so.1.3`).

When linking using the `-l` (lower-case L) flag you only specify `name`.

Also read more about the difference between `-l` which adds a library to link with, and `-L` which adds a *path* to look for libraries.

Comment: Maybe I should have commented `libc.so.6`

Comment: @iBug Probably should. Still a good point though, which I've added. :)

Answer (score 0):

On POSIX systems, library files are named as `libxxx.a` (for static libraries that'll be integrated into your executable) or `libxxx.so` (for dynamic libraries that'll be linked at runtime by `ld.so` (`ld-linux.so` for GNU/Linux)). Both can optionally carry a version suffix, like `libc.so.6`. Standard libraries and others that you have installed with your package manager (`apt`, `yum` or `pacman`) are located in `/lib` and `/usr/lib`.

When linking, you only need to specity it's name (i.e. `xxx`). Like when you want to link the math libary `libm.so`, compile your program with

```
gcc needMath.c -o needMath -lm
                           ~~^
```

On other platforms, you'd better look at the library provider's manual to determine the actual name to supply as command-line argument to the compiler. Manual is your friend.